# How can we pass values/parameters from android APK to React JS browser.?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-intent, react-router

We have an APK, in that we are calling "React-JS URL" in Android Web-View.
We are having one scenario in that 
Step 1. we have to pass the control from Browser to APK and
Step 2. pass the control with values/parameters again back to browser from APK.

We have done the step 1.
How can we achieve step 2.?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set data in hidden fields of react js UI from APK and trigger event from APK to React to read the same.

Comment: Also we can use window.***() method, which is accessible by both Android as well as React,